# Apply vertical centering to images with different sizes after image swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, vertical-alignment, fluid-layout

I'm currently using this script to cycle through images in a single folder.

```
$(function(){
  $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
    var self = this,
        file = this.src,
        common = file.substring(0, file.length-6)
        currentId =  +file.substr(-6,2),
        id = ('0' + (currentId+1)).substr(-2),
        nextimage = new Image();

    nextimage.onload = function(){
      // image was preloaded so it exists
      var img = this;
      $(self).fadeOut('slow', function(){self.src = img.src; $(self).fadeIn(300)});
    };
    nextimage.onerror = function(){
      // error occured while preloading. we assume image does not exist
      $(self).fadeOut('slow', function(){self.src = common+ '01.jpg'; $(self).fadeIn(300)});
    };
    nextimage.src = common + id + '.jpg';
  });
});
```

The Problem is the following: The images have all %-based sizes and are vertically allinged in a container with this script:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
  $( ".vertical").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      position:'relative',
      marginTop: ($(this).parent().outerHeight() 
                  - ($(this).outerHeight()+15))/2
    });
  });
});

$(window).load(function() {
  $( ".vertical").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      position:'relative',
      marginTop: ($(this).parent().outerHeight() 
                  - ($(this).outerHeight()+15))/2
    });
  });
});
```

Now: If the newly loaded image has a different height then the intial image, the vertical margin won't center the image because it uses the height of the initial image until I resize the window.

Is there a possibility to apply the margin top to each newly loaded image without resizing the window?

Here is the beta site: http://www.zeiteffekt.de/relaunch

Every help is very appreciated.

Comment: google search `css center image` will find numerous css methods that are not dependent on matching heights

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't answer my question. most css based solutions don't work with my fluid layout.

Comment: `most`? what about the others

Comment: If the images are inside a `display: block` container, you can simply apply `vertical-align: middle` and it will do the trick no matter what dimension system you are using (%, px, etc.)